# Trying to read tiff file using jai_imageio

Tags: servlets, tiff, javax.imageio, glassfish-4

I'm having some issue trying to create a subimage through a doGet method. I'm using  jai_imageio, the same method "getInvoiceNumberTif()" works fine when using the main method.But when I try to call the method from servlet I get an exception.

Heres the GET:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get </h1>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");

    FileHandler fh = new FileHandler();
    fh.getInvoiceNumberTif();

}
```

Here is the method:

```
public void getInvoiceNumberTif() throws IOException{

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\gideon\\Desktop\\tmp\\invoice.tif");

    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
    BufferedImage subImage = img.getSubimage(1600, 355, 220, 50);

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\gideon\\Desktop\\tmp\\img_invoice_nr.tif"));

    ImageIO.write(subImage, "tif", out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at se.visma.servlet.FileHandler.getInvoiceNumberTif(FileHandler.java:145)
at se.visma.servlet.InvoiceServlet.doGet(InvoiceServlet.java:126)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: I assume `img.getSubimage(...)` is the line that throws the exception, if not, please mark what is line 145. The problem is most likely incorrectly installed jai-imageio for your web app. Where do you place the libs? In the servers shared library folder, or in WEB-INF/lib as part of your web app?

Comment: When trouble shooting the issue I seem to get the error on  "BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file)" img is simple null. The jai_imageio jar is placed under web/lib in my intellij project. I try to place jar under WEB-INF/lib but the issue persists.

Comment: You can try this: [Deploying the plugins in a web app](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#deploying-the-plugins-in-a-web-app). Even though I made it for my own plugins, it should work just as good for the jai-imageio plugins.